# Why wont my python print on the same line?

Tags: python

```
question = "question:"
# QUESTION
f = open('dopeit.rtf', encoding="utf8", errors='ignore')

line = f.readline()

while line:

    if question in line:
        newline = line.replace('Question: ', '"')
        print(newline + '"', end=",")

    # use realine() to read next line
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
```

the output is something like this

```
","Who directed Star Wars?
","Who was the only non Jedi in the original Star Wars trilogy to use a lightsaber?
","What kind of flower was enchanted and dying in Beauty and the Beast?
","Which is the longest movie ever made?
```

I want it to be like this:

```
"Who directed Star Wars?","Who was the only non Jedi in the original Star Wars trilogy to use a lightsaber?","What kind of flower was enchanted and dying in Beauty and the Beast?","Which is the longest movie ever made?
```

So how can I make these changes? I tried using the "end" command but it still seems to bring it to the next line? Am I doing something wrong???

Comment: I'm guessing you have a newline character in the strings you are reading. Try newline.replace('\n', '')

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't change anything.... hm

Comment: What does ur file look like?

Comment: ApplePie you are right. I got it to work now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```py
newline = line.replace('Question: ', '"').replace("\n", "")
```